# int' to float' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++

I'm getting the conversion compiler error while converting from type_1 to type_2

```
CoordF character_coord() const { return character_coord_; };
void Set_character_coord(int x, int y) { character_coord_ = { x, y }; }; //line with error
void Set_character_coord(CoordF char_coord){ character_coord_ = char_coord; };

float vert_speed() const { return vert_speed_; };
void Set_vert_speed(float vert_speed) { vert_speed_ = vert_speed; };

camera_.Set_camera_coord({ screen_width_ / 2, screen_height_ / 2 }); //another example of same error 
camera_.Set_camera_size( screen_width_, screen_height_);
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would demonstrate the error. Your code snippet leaves a bit too much to the imagination...

Comment: But if I had to guess then I would say that the narrowing in this case is because float can only accurately represent 24 bits worth of integers, not the whole 32-bit range of int, so some accuracy may be lost. If you really want this, add an explicit conversion.

Answer (score -3):

{} operator implies that you do not want cast. Use () maybe

Comment: There are no **casts** involved here. The issue is about **conversions**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. You're right that `{}` means no narrowing conversions.